# Which radio/TV broadcasts were sampled by Bumblebee in the Transformers movies?

Tags: transformers, transformers-age-of-extinction, transformers-dark-of-the-moon, transformers-revenge-of-the-fallen, transformers-live-action-series

In the [*Transformer* movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_%28film_series%29), [Bumblebee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee_%28Transformers%29)'s voice actuator is fried. He speaks by rapidly cycling through satellite feeds and splicing together clips of speech from movies, music, TV, and radio. What are the the sources that Bumblebee samples for his speech? Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Below are sourced and unsourced quotes from all four Transformer movies. Each quote formatted to mention the audio sample clip first with the title and character who is being sampled, then each sample is accompanied directly below by context of the source clip and whom it was directed at. All source audio clips are tagged unconfirmed or unsourced audio samples accordingly.

Sources were acquired from, partly user submitted "trivia" on IMDB.com for each individual movie, and lots of self research use of the movies by googling the quotes and matching them to a source. Most quotes can be found on quodb.com

---

## *Transformers* (2007) Samples:

> `"Message from Starfleet."` voice of Lt. Uhura from *Star Trek*

- when explaining Bumblebee's origin.

> `"XM Satellite Radio... Digital cable brings you... ... Columbia Broadcasting System..."` [unsourced]

- when agreeing with Sam that Bumblebee talks through the radio.

> `"Across the inanimate vastness of space"` was taken from Orson Welles's infamous 1939 radio broadcast *The War of the Worlds*

- when explaining Bumblebee's origin.

> `"Any more questions you wanna ask?"` by John Wayne from *El Dorado*.

- Retorting to Sam and Mikaela, after explaining Bumblebee's origin.

> `"Thank you too. You're wonderful, you're wonderful."` **[unsourced]** (rumored Tom Cruise)

- when agreeing with Sam that Bumblebee talks through the radio.

> `"If there's anything you need, I wont be far away."` line from *Forest Gump*

- unconfirmed

> `"There are some things you just cant change."` line from *Forest Gump*.

- unconfirmed

> Samples `"Drive"` by The Cars

- to get Sam to give Mikaela a ride.

> Samples `"Sexual Healing"` by Marvin Gaye

- when he purposely broke down to give Sam & Mikaela some alone time.

> Samples `"Baby Come Back"` by Player

- when Mikaela started walking away.

> Samples `"Second to None"` by Styles of Beyond

- When introduced to Sam as his guardian

---

## *Transformers 2: Revenge of the Fallen* Samples:

> `"Houston we have a problem"` a line by Tom Hanks in *Apollo 13*

- spoken to Sam when Bumblebee turns up unannounced at college.

> `"We-We've got to stick together"` a line from James Stewart in *It's a Wonderful Life*
> `"everything we worked for will be wiped out. In one day"` a line from *High Noon*

- when convincing Sam not to hand him self in to the Decepticons.

> Samples `"Super Freak"` by Rick James
> Samples `"Your Cheatin' Heart"` by Hank Williams
> Samples *`Jaws`* attacking theme
> Samples `"Brick House"` by The Commodores

- When Decepticon transformer "Alice" is driving with Sam in Bumblebee.

> Samples `"I'm so excited"` by The Pointer Sisters

- When Sam says he is going to College

> `"They will rain down like visitors from heaven, Hallelujah!"`  **[unsourced]**

- unconfirmed

> `"His sacrifice for u will not have been in vain, Hallelujah."` **[unsourced]**
> `"Young fella`  **[unsourced]**
> `"you are the"`  **[unsourced]**
> `"person I care about most in my life."` Chris Farley line from *Black Sheep* (1996)

- to Sam after death of Optimus Prime (Around 1:13 mark).

---

## *Transformers 3: Dark of the Moon* Samples

> `"common"` **[unsourced]**
> `"Sam"` **[unsourced]**
> `"That"` **[unsourced]**
> `"Makes"` **[unsourced]**
> `"me"` **[unsourced]**
> `"Feel"` **[unsourced]**
> `"Bad"` **[unsourced]**

- When Sam Witwicky is telling Bumblebee how he doesn't see him anymore

> `"Did you eat a lot of paint chips when you were a kid?"` Line by Rob Lowe in *Tommy Boy*

- when talking to Bruce Brazos in Sam & Carlys apartment.

> `"missed it by that much"` Spoken by Maxwell Smart from *Get Smart*

- When Bumblebee smashes into chandelier in Sams & Carlys apartment.

> `"we going to do whatever we can"` **[unsourced]**
> `"make it like it was"` **[unsourced]**
> `"you"`  **[unsourced]**
> `"will always be"` **[unsourced]**
> `"My friend"` Spoken by Spock played by Leonard Nimoy from *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan*
> `"I gotta be going on"` Spoken by Alan Ladd in *Shane*

- When Bumblebee prepares to leave Earth with the Autobots

> `"good bye my old friend"` Spoken by Al Pacino in *The Godfather: Part III*

- When Q is killed by Soundwave

> `"Get off me!"` Spoken by Matt Damon from *Saving Private Ryan*

- when Soundwave grabs Bumblebee

> `"we had a hell of a run"` spoken by Nick Notle from *48 hrs* (credit to @goondocks)

- when Soundwave prepares to kill Bumblebee, spoken to Sam

> `"Ah I'm just trying to help out"` **[unsourced]**

- When Bumblebee tries to suggest Sam & Carly should marry.

---

## *Transformers 4: Age of Extinction* Samples:

> `"you know what"` **[unsourced]**
> `"just save us so much time"` **[unsourced]**

- When Hound and Drift are fighting after rendezvousing with Optimus Prime and the Yeagar family

> `"this child is about to"` spoken by DeForest Kelley in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*
> `"kick your ass"` **[unconfirmed]** Woody Harrelson from *White Men Can't Jump*

- When Drift says Bumblebee is like a child.

> `"you talking to me like that"` From the movie *The Untouchables* (1987) spoken by Robert De Niro
> `"now get out of here"`  by John Wayne from *El Dorado*.

- When Shane Dyson was riding shotgun in Bumblebee and said Stinger looked more bad ass

> `"son of a..."` By Chevy Chase in *Spies Like Us*

- When KSI advert talks about Stinger transformer being better than Bumblebee.

> `"I'm perfectly calm, dude"` from *The Big Lebowski* (1998). The quote is spoken by John Goodman's character.
> `"I'm calm! I'm calm, I'm not touching it. I'm barely touching it... I'm barely touching it"` **[unsourced]**
> `"Get out of my face, all right"` **[unconfirmed]** by Eddie Murphy in *Trading Places*
> `"What the ****"` is using the real voice of Bumblebee.
> `"Oh hell no!"` **[Unconfirmed]** by Samuel L Jackson in unknown movie.
> `"do you think, you're better than me"` **[unsourced]**
> `"I told you homeboy, can't touch this"` *Can't Touch this* by MC Hammer

- While in KSI headquarters in front of stinger, while Shane Dyson tries to calm him down

> `"Common"` **[unsourced]**
> `"lets get out of here"` **[unsourced]**

- When Bumblebee rescues Cade Yeagar from KSI

> `"And don't ever forget me"` **[unsourced]**

- when saving Yeagar family falling from anchor wires from spaceship

> `"I hate cheap knockoffs"` **[unsourced]**

- after killing Stinger

> `"Hey you guys"` **[unsourced]**
> `"Yeehaww"` **[unsourced]**

- When riding Swoop over double decker bus.

> `"You better listen"` **[unsourced]**

- When Tessa Yeager tells Bumblebee to "stop the car"

---

## *Transformers: The Last Knight* Samples:

> `"I'm tired of people messin with me"` From *Eddie Murphy Raw (1987)* Spoken by Eddie Murphy

- when fighting sentinels in Chicago.

> `"Next time you shoot somebody, don't go near 'em till you're sure they're dead."` From *El Dorado (1967)* spoken by John Wayne as Cole Thornton

- when attacking the TRF in Chicago

> `"I'll burn you so bad you'll wish you'd died as a child"` From *Good Morning, Vietnam (1987)* spoken by J.T. Walsh as Sergeant Major Dickerson

- when attacking the TRF in Chicago (spoken to Santos)

> `"Shut up."` [unsourced]
> `"Before I do some damage you won't walk away from."` From *True Romance (1993)* spoken by Christopher Walken as Vincenzo Coccotti
> `"You talk too much"` [unsourced]

- when retorting back to Drift that he caused the incident in Chicago from the previous scene and isn't fit to be the autobots leader

> Samples `Hammer Time` by Mc Hammer

- when Cade says he's going to install Bee's new voice modulator.

> `"What the hell?"` [unsourced]

- after Bulldog fires a warning shot at Cade and co

> Samples `I Don't Fuck With You` by Big Sean (Feat E-40)

- When Sir Edmund Burton says he met BumbleBee as a kid many years ago.

> `"Thats how you get to the big leagues"` From *Barbershop: The Next Cut* (2016)

- when BumbleBee shoots Barricade during London car chase

> `"What?! Are you serious?!"` [unsourced]
> `"Think I like winding up in a place like this?"` [unsourced]

- When Cade tells BumbleBee to find another entrance to the ignition chamber ship.

> `"No, they all messed up"` [unsourced]

- When talking about the Knight bots on board the Autobot ship.

> `"I sting like a bee!"` Spoken by BumbleBees real voice (actor Erik Aadahl)

- When Optimus Prime distracts Quintessa and BumbleBee appears behind Quintessa and blasts her

Comment: Where did you find these quotes? It looks like it's taken form somewhere...Either way, good find!

Comment: main ones are sourced from IMDB and some others are randomly found from questions asked @ answers yahoo. Some I've remembered and peiced together myself. Theres still a lot of samples he uses to directly communicate, left to be found :).

Comment: I've rewatched 1 and 2 to piece more samples/quotes together and researched them myself. Plan to watch Dark of the Moon again soon and build the last list of samples and quotes. In mean time if anyone finds anything please feel free to leave your answer =]

Comment: I don't obviously have a copy of *Age of Extinction* yet but when it is released I will buy it and sit through every Bumblebee scene again to research any sources :) The ones currently listed here, were made available from footage on youtube.com.

Comment: `I gotta be going on` in Transformers Dark of the Moon sounds like a slightly edited version from Shane(1953) with a reverb. Comparison: Transformers Dark of the Moon - https://youtu.be/eWdv4fkYmTg?t=396 Shane - https://youtu.be/d8S6T1ErGl4?t=47

Comment: "Young fella, you are the person I care about most in my life." 


"Young fella" is not Farley"

"You are" is also not Farley and not the same person who says "young fella"

"person i care about most in my life" is from Black Sheep after Farley's character's brother basically tells him he screwed everything up and to leave him alone. It's about 51 minutes in.

Comment: @Michael thanks I have checked both and you are right, updating accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The quote

> person I care about most in my life

sounds like [Chris Farley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Farley).

Comment: Confirmed from user @Michael yes this is from Black Sheep 1996 movie spoken by Chris Farley.

Answer (score 1):

**Age of Extinction:**

Here are a few that I think, but I'm trying to identify the sources:

- When he says "This child is about to...kick your ass."

  - I believe the "kick your ass" part is Woody Harrelson from White Men Can't Jump since it's one of the few movies credited in the end credits. Can't identify the first part.
- "You talk to me like that?"

  - No idea.
- "Now get out of here."

  - sounds like John Wayne, possible from High Noon as the movie has been sampled for Bumblebee's voice in earlier movies, but could also be Chevy Chase from Spies Like Us as it is credited in the end credits.
- "Son of a..."

  - This also sounds like Chevy Chase from Spies Like Us.
- "I'm calm, I'm calm. I'm not even touching it. I'm barely touching it"

  - sounds like David Cross, but not sure.
- "Get outta my face, alright?"

  - sounds like Eddie Murphy, possibly from 48 Hours as a Nick Nolte soundbite from 48 Hours was used in one of the other movies.

Comment: I've changed the formatting of your answer. Feel free to rollback the edit if you don't agree with the changes.

Comment: @Goondocks - Hey great find, I'll go away and verify them all. Do you know what Nick Notle soundbite was used in previous TF films?

Comment: Thanks! In Revenge of the Fallen when Soundwave is about to execute Bumblebee. "We gave them a hell of a run." is Nick Nolte as Jack Cates from 48 Hours.

Comment: Just confirmed that, thanks! Couldn't find the line "get outta my face,alright" in the 48 hrs script, possibly different Eddie Murphy movie? If you find any more let me know :)

Comment: Also, the first part of "This child is about to..." is from Star Trek - Bones McCoy.

-The "You talk to me like that?" is probably DeNiro in Untouchables, according to a friend of mine.

-The "You know what..." (first time Bee speaks) sounds like Forrest Gump.

-The "You damn right!" Could be from Bad Boys, but don't know what "and don't you forget it" is from.

(Need formatting help again lol)

Comment: The "Get outta my face, alright?" is most likely Eddie Murphy from Trading Places.

Comment: @Goondocks - I searched everywhere to source "I'm calm, I'm calm, I'm barely touching it" as it seems quite a popular quote on tumblr. Yet I could not find any clues as to whom originally said it. It sounds a little like Chris Rock at the start but not at the end so I doubt it is him. Have you had any luck finding more? I've finished all the audio samples but haven't sourced them all.

Answer (score 0):

"You're wonderful, you're wonderful." is by Tom Cruise, though we don't know which movie it appears in.

Comment: Magnolia maybe?

Answer (score -1):

The `"Shut up."` in *Transformers: The Last Knight* came from *School of Rock*.

Comment: Do you know who spoke the line, and the scene in which it was spoken?